# Scroll в модальном окне без исчезновения эффектов

Tags: html, css

Как добавить scroll в модальном окне, чтобы он появлялся только тогда, когда высота текста превышает высоту окна и при этом сохранить все эффекты? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Нижнего скролла не должно быть

HTML:

```
    <div class="container-modal-window-easy-difficult">
    <div class="modal-window-easy-difficult">
        <div class="header-easy-difficult">EASY</div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="text-modal-window-easy-difficult">
                The Easy difficulty level on our website is the perfect starting point for those who are just beginning
                their journey into the world of tasks and challenges. Here, you will find puzzles and tasks that provide an
                inspiring challenge but won't be overly difficult. With this level of difficulty, you can familiarize
                yourself with basic concepts and patterns, which will gradually help you develop your skills and move on to
                more serious challenges. Raise the bar of your knowledge with ease and confidence as you prepare for more
                complex trials ahead.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-btn">
            <button class="close-btn">CLOSE</button>
            <button class="next-btn">NEXT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #16171b;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container-modal-window-easy-difficult {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 600px;
}

@property --gradient-angle {
    syntax: "<angle>";
    initial-value: 0deg;
    inherits: false;
}

:root {
    --clr-1: #052b2f;
    --clr-2: #073438;
    --clr-3: #0e4b50;
    --clr-4: #2d578f;
    --clr-5: #0038ad;
}

.modal-window-easy-difficult{
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
    background: var(--clr-1);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;

    position: relative;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

.modal-window-easy-difficult::before,
.modal-window-easy-difficult::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: -0.5rem;
    z-index: -1;
    background: conic-gradient(
            from var(--gradient-angle),
            var(--clr-3),
            var(--clr-4),
            var(--clr-5),
            var(--clr-4),
            var(--clr-3)
    );
    border-radius: inherit;
    animation: rotation 5s linear infinite;
}

.modal-window-easy-difficult::after {
    filter: blur(3.5rem);
}

@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        --gradient-angle: 0deg;
    }
    100% {
        --gradient-angle: 360deg;
    }
}

/* SCROLLBAR */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #0e4b50;
    width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #0038ad;
}

/* CONTENT */
.header-easy-difficult {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;

    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0038ad;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    filter: brightness(300%);

    user-select: none;
}


.text-modal-window-easy-difficult {
    padding: 10px 15px 15px;

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #c1c1c1;;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* BUTTON CLOSE */
.container-btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.close-btn{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #050801;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close-btn:hover{
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #050801;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px red,
    0 0 25px darkred;
    /*0 0 25px #03e9f4;*/
    /*0 0 50px #03e9f4,*/
    /*0 0 200px #03e9f4;*/
    -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}

/* BUTTON NEXT */
.next-btn{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #050801;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.next-btn:hover{
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #050801;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px #03e9f4;
    /*0 0 50px #03e9f4,*/
    /*0 0 200px #03e9f4;*/
    -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}
```

Comment: overflow-y: auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать добавить дополнительную обёртку внутрь `.modal-window-easy-difficult`
В моём случае это `.modal-content`

И добавить туда `overflow-y: auto`:

```css
.modal-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.container-btn {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Полный код:

```css
body {
    background-color: #16171b;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container-modal-window-easy-difficult {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 600px;
}

@property --gradient-angle {
    syntax: "<angle>";
    initial-value: 0deg;
    inherits: false;
}

:root {
    --clr-1: #052b2f;
    --clr-2: #073438;
    --clr-3: #0e4b50;
    --clr-4: #2d578f;
    --clr-5: #0038ad;
}

.modal-window-easy-difficult{
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
    background: var(--clr-1);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;

    position: relative;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

.modal-window-easy-difficult::before,
.modal-window-easy-difficult::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: -0.5rem;
    z-index: -1;
    background: conic-gradient(
            from var(--gradient-angle),
            var(--clr-3),
            var(--clr-4),
            var(--clr-5),
            var(--clr-4),
            var(--clr-3)
    );
    border-radius: inherit;
    animation: rotation 5s linear infinite;
}

.modal-window-easy-difficult::after {
    filter: blur(3.5rem);
}

@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        --gradient-angle: 0deg;
    }
    100% {
        --gradient-angle: 360deg;
    }
}

/* SCROLLBAR */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #0e4b50;
    width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #0038ad;
}

/* CONTENT */
.header-easy-difficult {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;

    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0038ad;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    filter: brightness(300%);

    user-select: none;
}


.text-modal-window-easy-difficult {
    padding: 10px 15px 15px;

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #c1c1c1;;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* BUTTON CLOSE */
.container-btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.close-btn{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #050801;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close-btn:hover{
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #050801;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px red,
    0 0 25px darkred;
    /*0 0 25px #03e9f4;*/
    /*0 0 50px #03e9f4,*/
    /*0 0 200px #03e9f4;*/
    -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}

/* BUTTON NEXT */
.next-btn{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #050801;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.next-btn:hover{
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #050801;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px #03e9f4;
    /*0 0 50px #03e9f4,*/
    /*0 0 200px #03e9f4;*/
    -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}

/* ---> my css below <--- */

.modal-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.container-btn {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-modal-window-easy-difficult">
    <div class="modal-window-easy-difficult">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="header-easy-difficult">EASY</div>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="text-modal-window-easy-difficult">
                    The Easy difficulty level on our website is the perfect starting point for those who are just
                    beginning
                    their journey into the world of tasks and challenges. Here, you will find puzzles and tasks that
                    provide an
                    inspiring challenge but won't be overly difficult. With this level of difficulty, you can
                    familiarize
                    yourself with basic concepts and patterns, which will gradually help you develop your skills and
                    move on to
                    more serious challenges. Raise the bar of your knowledge with ease and confidence as you prepare for
                    more
                    complex trials ahead.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi tempore quod laudantium debitis
                    consectetur suscipit nostrum nesciunt, id rerum, eaque atque, sequi hic molestiae unde! Nulla
                    cupiditate voluptatum eaque quos!
                    Sapiente dignissimos cum tempore consequatur. Sequi veritatis sit voluptatum iure? Doloribus
                    aperiam, illum dolore, itaque ad velit iure neque quis architecto voluptatum exercitationem eius
                    dolorum mollitia voluptate voluptatem quam incidunt!
                    Amet, sit natus! Minima optio cumque animi omnis facere pariatur officia voluptate magni odio totam,
                    esse quia nulla saepe modi. Esse, eaque vitae obcaecati nihil autem nesciunt eos et harum!
                    Deleniti quibusdam eligendi ratione ducimus temporibus, alias officia adipisci excepturi quod
                    commodi. Ullam vel reprehenderit eligendi? Reiciendis, voluptates? Minus porro eligendi modi quos a
                    ea, corrupti error veritatis tenetur cum?
                    Deleniti repudiandae commodi eum ducimus. Debitis quam cupiditate optio natus, asperiores dolorum.
                    Ducimus magni culpa rerum. Illo excepturi, expedita provident nesciunt est harum molestiae, iure
                    corrupti, porro explicabo impedit ad.
                    Fugiat repellat laborum nemo facere enim commodi velit ut quam quidem porro. A suscipit architecto
                    quo repellat amet dolorem, nulla, ducimus enim animi vel dicta corporis. Sequi saepe aliquam
                    repellendus.
                    Qui, iste exercitationem, explicabo ab sequi ex odio ipsum hic deleniti soluta quibusdam officia
                    voluptas tempore. Quo cum doloribus assumenda reiciendis, dignissimos, ex necessitatibus nesciunt,
                    inventore totam dolorem numquam excepturi?
                    Nobis itaque dolor quam officia, aspernatur hic aliquid. Quod saepe, eius repellat ut quos officiis
                    quae, quia a, mollitia non unde recusandae? Adipisci incidunt placeat dicta esse hic. Hic, rem?
                    Molestiae ipsa architecto placeat quibusdam eius illum velit totam, laboriosam accusamus, quas ab.
                    Facere quia hic alias! Laborum id necessitatibus ex aut sunt eius incidunt, deleniti nostrum quo
                    voluptatem minus.
                    Dolore fugiat veniam nostrum corrupti voluptas! Voluptatibus magnam quo illum nam, veritatis
                    perferendis dignissimos omnis quibusdam reprehenderit aperiam nemo sunt assumenda iure sequi impedit
                    porro consequatur fuga inventore? Eveniet, culpa.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-btn">
                <button class="close-btn">CLOSE</button>
                <button class="next-btn">NEXT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```